# noscript text is appearing in Google

Tags: seo, noscript, google-index

I have added  in the bottom of my html like this (just like how stackoverflow has it implemented):

```
<noscript>This site works best with Javascript is enabled</noscript>
```

but in one of my pages that has very little text, the text "Javascript is disabled" appears in Google search.

[image]

Is there a way to tell Google to avoid indexing this part? Or is there a better alternative instead of using `<noscript>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Google often won't render Javascript. It can - but it often won't.

You either need to present a [pre-rendered page](https://prerender.io/) or provide it with a meta description that accurately describes the content. Look up  tags and how Google uses them to embellish it's search listings.

Other options like  or  can encourage Google from deviating from the provided description. However, a pre-rendered page for it to scrape is always more reliable.